# When altering the submit button, the form does not work

Tags: forms, search

We need a `<button>` instead of an input in our search-form. So I changed the markup accordingly using `theme_form_alter`:

```
function giga_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['search_block_form']['#title'] = t('Search'); // Change the text on the label element
    $form['search_block_form']['#title_display'] = 'invisible'; // Toggle label visibilty
    $form['search_block_form']['#size'] = 40;  // define size of the textfield
    $form['search_block_form']['#default_value'] = t('Search'); // Set a default value for the textfield
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type'   => 'markup',
      '#prefix' => '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">',
      '#suffix' => '</button>',
      '#markup' => '<i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>'
    );
    $form['actions']['submit']['#executes_submit_callback'] = true;
    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'none';
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-quick';

    // Alternative (HTML5) placeholder attribute instead of using the javascript
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search');
  }
}
```

However, I can submit the form, but the search won't be processed. The page reloads and I'm not redirect to the search results. However when I remove `$form['actions']['submit'] = array([…]);` it all works fine.

I'm not quite sure what's going on here.

Comment: In order for the form to be submitted correctly the element needs to be a `submit`, `button` or `image_button` type. An element of type `markup` can never invoke a form submission as it doesn't make semantic sense. You can actually infer that from the docs for [`#executes_submit_callback`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#executes_submit_callback) themselves

Comment: Yes, to expand on what Clive said, a form array does two jobs: (1) telling the API what HTML to generate for a form, and (2) telling it how to process input from it. Your code is doing the first one without the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

Drupal 6:

```
 $form['actions']['submit']['#type'] = "Submit";
```

Drupal 7:

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
  '#type'  => 'submit',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. All the needed was adding this.

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
  '#type'  => 'submit',
);
```