# Form submit handler not working

Tags: 7, forms

I'm developing a pretty basic module `catalog_request` that creates a form. I'm replacing the form's default submit button `<input ..type="submit" />` with a `<button ...>click</button>` using following in form definition.

```
function catalog_request_form($form, &$form_state) {

    /**
     * form fields here
     */

    $form['fieldset_submit']['the_submit_button'] = array(
       '#type' => 'markup',
       '#prefix' => '<button class="btn submit">',
       '#markup' => 'Send Request...',
       '#suffix' => '</button>',
    );

    /* ... */
}
```

and have defined other two form related functions

```
function catalog_request_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The form was validated'));
}

function catalog_request_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    die('submitted');
    //drupal_set_message(t('The form was submitted'));
}
```

**The problem**

My submit function `catalog_request_form_submit` isn't being called. I've read numerous articles online but none resolved my issue. Following didn't work

1. Adding `'#submit' => 'catalog_request_form_submit',` to
   `the_submit_button` key
2. Adding `'$form['#submit'] => 'catalog_request_form_submit';` to end
   of `catalog_request_form` function
3. Adding `'$form['#submit'][] => 'catalog_request_form_submit';` to
   end of `catalog_request_form` function

I've read that adding something along the lines of `$form['actions']['#submit'][] = 'custom_function';` could solve the problem but I'm not sure how to adapt it for my form.

I know that having `'#type' => 'submit'` for the submit button makes the form work but I want a `button` tag.

My problem is exactly [When altering the submit button, the form does not work](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64871/when-altering-the-submit-button-the-form-does-not-work) but it doesn't have a *solution* (only an answer that ignores the question's point)

P.S. I do not develop for drupal frequently so I might be missing something very obvious.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Instead of adding a **button** you can use another **custom submit** button? And why you need a **button**?

Comment: Also **buttons** will not submit a form. Try to use another form submit button. Refer [Handle multiple submit buttons in Drupal form API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501890/handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-drupal-form-api)

Comment: The real question is _why_ you're stuck on using a `<button>` where it doesn't make sense to use one. If you want something that submits the form, use a submit input, which was created for that specific purpose.

Comment: I know that `<input ... type="submit"../>` submits the form. I know that using `'#type'=>'submit'` generates an `input` element. But I have to use `<button...>`. why? I'll start with "`button` can have HTML content". The `<input ... type="submit"../>` and `<button..>` both submit the form in all browsers I care about so there is no issue there. There are ways _around_ every issue and I'm willing to get around this issue when somebody proves that there is no way this problem can be resolved in Durpal. Drupal is the problem here, not my HTML.
thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to add another submit handler you have to add something to `hook_form_alter()`: check for your particular form ID, and then add a submit handler in one of the following ways:

**OPTION 1:**

To add a submit handler that is called as the next callback *after* processing the default submit handler callback you can use this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_id == 'form-id-of-your-form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_whatever_function';
  }
}
```

**OPTION 2:**

If OPTION 1 is not working for you, replace the third line with this:

```
form['#submit'][1] = 'mymodule_whatever_function';
```

This will add a second submit handler, or replace the second one with yours if there is already more than one.

**OPTION 3:**

To remove the default submit handler completely (so that "nothing will happen" on submit, or so that you can replace it with your own), use code like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_id == 'form-id-of-your-form') {
    unset($form["actions"]['submit']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided:

> "In order for the form to be submitted correctly the element needs to be a submit, button or image_button type."

So maybe something like the following will work.

```
$form['fieldset_submit']['the_submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#name' => 'name',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE,
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately `'#type' => 'button'` generates an input element, not a button element

Answer (score 0):

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_button/7

You can write something like this in your theme

```
function THEMENAME_button($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'submit';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value'));

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'];
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['disabled'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-button-disabled';
  }

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

and change markup for you needs.

Internet Explorer 6-7 doesn't work with button value attribute.

**Update**

```
function THEMENAME_button($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'submit';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value'));

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'];
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['disabled'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-button-disabled';
  }

  return '<button' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>'. $element['#attributes']['value'] .'</button>';
}
```

Comment: it seems to output an `<input...>` element not `<button...>`

Comment: It's standard theme_button function. You can change it in your theme.

Answer (score -3):

If you are rendering your form using form--anyformname.tpl.php template file then make sure in that template file you are rendering these three thing at the end:

```
    <div>        
    <?php print render($form['form_id']); ?>
    <?php print render($form['form_build_id']);?>
    <?php print render($form['form_token']); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: The OP is not using a theme, but a module.

Comment: In that module did u created a filename.tpl.php file,  if created then make sure all hidden child element should in form when it get render.